# Função asset do laravel não está referenciando

Tags: php, laravel, framework

Tenho um projeto e sinceramente não sei o que eu fiz de diferente, mas na hora de abrir ele, do nada todas as imagens, arquivos `css` e `javascript` não estão sendo referenciados.

Estou utilizando o `laravel`, e referenciando da seguinte maneira:

```
<link href="{{ asset('/css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Quando eu abro o console do navegador, me deparo com um erro pra cada imagem, arquivo `css` ou `javascript`, do  tipo:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   http://localhost:8000/css/bootstrap.css

Os arquivos estão dentro da pasta `projeto/laravel/public`, como deve ser e como sempre funcionou.

Já tentei voltar para versões anteriores no `git` mas não ajuda.

Já tentei em outro computador mas também nenhum resultado.

Alguém tem ideia do que possa ser?

Comment: Asset vai à pasta assets que se estiveres a usar laravel >= 5 está dentro da pasta resources. Tenta o seguinte `{{ url('/css/bootstrap.css') }}`

Comment: Então, eu acabei de testar também passando todos os arquivos da pasta public para a pasta resources/assets, mesmo assim não funciona.

Também já tentei utilizar url('/css/bootstrap.css'), mas sem sucesso. Inclusive tentei URL::asset('') e url('assets/'), mas nada.

Obrigado mesmo assim

Comment: Sua outras rotas funcionam normalmente? Não teria alguma impactando nos seus arquivos publicos?

Comment: Estás a correr a app com o artisan? ou diretamente na pasta public?

Comment: @KennyRafael sim, as outras rotas funcionam normalmente. Eu tentei inclusive reverter para uma versão mais antiga no git, mas mesmo assim não consegui fazer esse problema parar. Pensei que poderia ser algo no apache, mas não mexi nada nele. 
sim, php artisan serve

Comment: Teria como testar ele em outro server, não sei se vc tem uma produção...alguns erros no laravel aconteceram comigo somente em dev, mais de uma vez...

Comment: Como você está chamando o site, digite o endereço aqui por exemplo que está tendo problema?

Comment: Eu estou rodando ele apenas local, não tenho nenhum servidor por enquanto. Testar em outro server significa testar em outro computador, no caso?

Comment: Estou tento o mesmo problema, alguém conseguiu uma solução pro caso?

Answer (score 0):

Vou responder essa pergunta porque tive um mesmo problema quando fiz o deploy do meu projeto para a produção e eu não consegui encontrar a resposta em lugar nenhum.

Para configurar a URL dos Assets do seu projeto, é necessário alterar a propridade `'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', null)` do seu arquivo `config/app.php`.

Antes de fazer o deploy para produção, é necessário alterar o valor `null` para a pasta onde estão os assets, ex. `asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', '/public/')`. Quando você fizer essa alteração, é necessário colocar a propriedade `ASSET_URL = null` no seu arquivo `.env`, para que os assets sejam localizados também em desenvolvimento.